# Alignment of elements in row of react native header

Tags: reactjs, react-native, flexbox

I have a header section in my react native app where I want - on one row - to display two bits of info, a back button icon, and some text. I am trying to figure out how to arrange these elements so that the back button icon aligns to the horizontal left of the full width of the line, while the text for the client name horizontally aligns at the center of that line. So that means on the right there will just be empty space.

The one way I've gotten this to work thus far feels a little hacky, as it involves creating a 3rd element, with the same proportions as the 1st one, and then just not declaring the name of the `Feather` icon element. In other words, this works because it aligns the center item between two items aligned to the left and right, even though with the right one, nothing is actually showing on the screen. Is there a less hacky way of doing this, that involves not adding a 3rd "invisible" element?

```
<View style={{ width: '100%', flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>
  <Feather
    name='chevron-left'
    size={24}
    onPress={() => props.navigation.goBack()}
    color={styles.colors.textInverse}
    style={{ justifySelf: 'flex-start', alignSelf: 'flex-start' }}
  />
  <Text style={{ color: '#fff', fontSize: 18, alignSelf: 'center', justifySelf: 'center' }}>
    {props?.client?.firstName} {props?.client?.lastName}
  </Text>
  <Feather
    name='' // Leave this blank
    style={{ justifySelf: 'flex-end', alignSelf: 'flex-end' }}
  />
</View>
```

Comment: That's the simplest way to do it. Believe me, you don't want to add extra calculations on the space taken by the left view to style the text to be centered, it will be more complex to implement, maintain and read, and probably worse in performance. Adding a 3rd view also allows you to add a right element.

Comment: I no nothing of React, but in plain CSS with parent `justify-content: space-between` both the left button and the text need `margin-right: auto` and the right, empty button `margin-left: auto`. Remove child elements self alignment. If a none React answer is acceptable, I'll put it down there... The right element and CSS for that can be removed.

Comment: Yes, please do. And even better, as the answer below discusses, perhaps the key is to use `padding-right` (which is `paddingRight` in react), in order to handle the center screen alignment of the text element, rather than using an "imaginary" 3rd element.

Answer (score 4):

Use `paddingRight` for `Text` to balance out the item on the left. Something like this:

```
<View style={{ width: '100%', flexDirection: 'row' }}>
  <Feather
    name='chevron-left'
    size={24}
...
  />
  <Text style={{ textAlign: 'center', flex: 1, paddingRight: 24 }}>
    ...
  </Text>
</View>
```

Comment: This seems to work pretty well. And what I'm doing in addition is passing in a precise `width` of 32% for the left element, and `paddingRight` of 32% for the center-aligned element.